# Making for loop ignore something first time through

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am working on an encryption assignment for my CS class and where are using a logistic map for part of changing the characters with ord() and chr().

for my code I am using a for loop and I need it to run once before using a certain command(logMap)

```
from logistic import logMap
from genAmpSeed import genAmpSeed
from cipherChr import cipherChr

password=input("Enter password: ")
amp,seed=genAmpSeed(password)
line=input("Enter line to cipher: ")

def logMap(a,x):
    ans=(a*x)*(1-x)
    return ans

def line2cipher(amp,seed,line):
    acc=''
    for i in line:
        res=logMap(amp,seed)
        offset=int(96*res)
        acc+= cipherChr(i,offset)
    print(acc,res)
```

So I need this to run but the first time by using the defaults from genAmpSeed ([genAmpSeed.py](http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/~shira/cs111/hw/genAmpSeed.py)) the first time and then use the logMap defaults from then on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slice to ignore the first character of the string.

```
def line2cipher(amp,seed,line):
    acc=''
    for i in line[1:]:
        res=logMap(amp,seed)
        offset=int(96*res)
        acc+= cipherChr(i,offset)
    print(acc,res)
```

**EDIT:**

If you want something more generic, you can use a flag to check if it's the first time the loop is running:

```
first = True
for i in range(10):
    if first:
        first = False
        # Do whatever you need to do for the first time
        continue
    # Do something...
```